# Threadsafe mutable collection with fast elements removal and random get

Tags: multithreading, scala, collections

I need a thread safe data structure with three operations: remove, getRandom, reset.
I have only two ideas by now.

First: Seq in syncronized var.

```
val all: Array[String] =  ... //all possible.
var current: Array[String] = Array.empty[String]

def getRandom(): = {
  val currentAvailable = current
  currentAvailable(Random.nextInt(currentAvailable.length))
}

def remove(s: String) = {
  this.syncronized {
     current = current diff Seq(s)
  }
}

def reset(s: String) = {
  this.syncronized {
     current = all
  }
}
```

Second:
Maintain some Map[String,Boolean], there bool is true when element currently is present. The main problem is to make a fast getRandom method (not something like O(n) in worst case).

Is there a better way(s) to implement this?

Comment: do you want to get random var and then remove it?

Comment: Nope. This should be separate actions.

Comment: Alright mate, I'm not a scala expert, but as a general idea I can show you an example in lets say java. if you want

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: before I go on, could your data set contain duplicates?

Comment: well, on-nom-nom answered your question by a simple link :D. the main idea is to use **Maping**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Scala's Trie](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap) is a lock free data structure that supports snapshots (aka your `currentAvailable`) and fast removals

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not a Scala expert so this answer is general as an example I used Java coding.

in short the answer is YES.
if you use a map such as :

```
Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  //is used to get random in constant time
Map<String,Integer> map1=new HashMap<String,Integer>();  //is used to remove in constant time
```

to store date,
the main idea is to keep the key( in this case the integer) synchronized to be {1 ... size of map}
for example to fill this structure, you need something like this:

```
int counter=0; //this is a global variable
for(/* all your string (s) in all */ ){
  map.put(counter++, s);
}   
//then , if you want the removal to be in constant time you need to fill the second map
for(Entry e : map.EntrySet(){
  map1.put(e.getValue(),e.getKey());
}
```

The above code is the initialization. everytime you want to set things you need to do that

then you can achieve a random value with O(1) complexity

```
String getRandom(){
int i; /*random number between 0 to counter*/
return map.get(i);
}
```

Now to remove things you use map1 to achive it in constant time O(1);

```
void remove(String s){
   if(!map1.containsKey(s))
      return; //s doesn't exists

   String val=map.get(counter);  //value of the last 
   map.remove(counter)           //removing the last element
   int thisCounter= map1.get(s); //pointer to this
   map1.remove(s);               // remove from map1
   map.remove(counter);          //remove from map
   map1.put(thisCounter,val);    //the val of the last element with the current pointer
   counter--;                    //reducing the counter by one
}
```

obviously the main issue here is to keep the synchronization ensured. but by carefully analyzing the code you should be able to do that.